# Is there a debugger "statement" for Haskell/GHCi/something else?

Tags: debugging, haskell

### Background

I am learning about GHCi's :break feature. JS has a built in statement called `debugger;` which acts as a breakpoint if debugging is in progress, does nothing otherwise.

### Question

Is there a similar statement/function for Haskell/GHCi?

### Further specification

I am thinking something along the lines of `Debug.Trace.trace :: String -> a -> a`.

It is okay if it uses `unsafePerformIO` internally, or relies on something GHCi specific as it is only meant for debugging.

Or if there is nothing yet, couldn't something like this be achieved with `:set -fbreak-on-exception` and having a function that throws an exception and catches it immediately? (`unsafePerformIO` may be needed here as well, so that the function can be placed in pure code.)

Answer (score 5):

You don't need it.

It is much better to have your code clean than full of debugging insertions.

With *ghci* you can set a breakpoint by function name or by line number wherever you want. From ghci :help

```
   :break [<mod>] <l> [<col>]  set a breakpoint at the specified location
   :break <name>               set a breakpoint on the specified function
```

**Alternative** :

Even more, you can keep a list of breakpoints in a project based [./.ghci](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/ghci-dot-files.html) command batch file, loaded automatically at ghci start.

Answer (score 3):

If you really want that, you can define your own identity function

```
debugger :: a -> a
debugger x = x
```

and `:break debugger` in GHCi.

Comment: This neither give you access to the variable bindings of the calling function, nor permits you to step back into the calling function unless you previously create another breakpoint there. [Am I right?](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/ghci-debugger.html#single-stepping)

Comment: @GabrielRiba `:trace`,`:hist` and `:back` seem to work